# Python class inheritance - spooky action

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I've observed a strange effect with class inheritance. For the project I'm working on, I'm creating a class to act as a wrapper to another module's class.

I am using the 3rd-party aeidon module (used for manipulating subtitle files) but the issue is probably less specific.

Here is how you'd normally utilize the module...

```
project = aeidon.Project()
project.open_main(path)
```

Here is the example 'wrapper' class in use (of course the real class has many methods):

```
class Wrapper(aeidon.Project):
    pass

project = Wrapper()
project.open_main(path)
```

This aforementioned code raises an *AttributeError* upon execution. However, the following works as I originally expected it to:

```
junk = aeidon.Project()
project = Wrapper()
project.open_main(path)
```

I named this question after spooky action at a distance because I suspect that it involves global vars/objects in the environment, but I don't know.

I ended up using composition to solve this problem (i.e. `self.project = aeidon.Project()`) but I'm still curious about this. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Here is the traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-fe548abd7ad0> in <module>()
----> 1 project.open_main(path)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aeidon/deco.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    208     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    209         frozen = args[0].freeze_notify()
--> 210         try: return function(*args, **kwargs)
    211         finally: args[0].thaw_notify(frozen)
    212     return wrapper

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aeidon/agents/open.py in open_main(self, path, encoding)
    161         format = aeidon.util.detect_format(path, encoding)
    162         self.main_file = aeidon.files.new(format, path, encoding)
--> 163         subtitles = self._read_file(self.main_file)
    164         self.subtitles, sort_count = self._sort_subtitles(subtitles)
    165         self.set_framerate(self.framerate, register=None)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aeidon/project.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    116             return self._delegations[name]
    117         except KeyError:
--> 118             raise AttributeError
    119 
    120     def __init__(self, framerate=None, undo_limit=None):

AttributeError:
```

I've tried it both with and without a call to Project's `__init__()`. Obviously this is not really something that should be done under normal circumstances, I'm just perplexed why Wrapper() would function as expected only after creating a junk aeidon.Project().

Comment: This is probably specific to the `aeidon` project, but we cannot tell because you did not include the full traceback.

Comment: ipython3 v2.3.1 but I also tested it in python3 v3.4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`aedion.project` module](https://github.com/otsaloma/gaupol/blob/35a024ab18eec7f4c97f9425c887db573466c857/aeidon/project.py) does two things:

- It adds methods from classes in the `aedion.agents` package to the class, in order for the documentation generator to include these when extracting docstrings and other information, using a [`ProjectMeta` metaclass](https://github.com/otsaloma/gaupol/blob/35a024ab18eec7f4c97f9425c887db573466c857/aeidon/project.py#L25-L50):

  ```
  class ProjectMeta(type):

      """
      Project metaclass with delegated methods added.
      Public methods are added to the class dictionary during :meth:`__new__`
      in order to fool Sphinx (and perhaps other API documentation generators)
      into thinking that the resulting instantiated class actually contains those
      methods, which it does not since the methods are removed during
      :meth:`Project.__init__`.
      """
  ```

  these methods, if used, would not be correctly bound however.
- The `Project.__init__` method calls [`Project._init_delegations()`](https://github.com/otsaloma/gaupol/blob/35a024ab18eec7f4c97f9425c887db573466c857/aeidon/project.py#L138-L158). This method **deletes** the delegated methods from the class:

  ```
  # Remove class-level function added by ProjectMeta.
  if hasattr(self.__class__, attr_name):
      delattr(self.__class__, attr_name)
  ```

  Note the use of `self.__class__` here. This is needed because Python won't look for the delegated method via the `__getattr__` hook if the method is found on the class instead.

  The delegated methods are bound to a dedicated agent instance, so are in fact delegating to that agent:

  ```
  agent = getattr(aeidon.agents, agent_class_name)(self)
  # ...
  attr_value = getattr(agent, attr_name)
  # ...
  self._delegations[attr_name] = attr_value
  ```

When you create a wrapper around this class, the *deletion* step fails. `self.__class__` is your wrapper, not the base `Project` class. Thus the methods are bound incorrectly; the metaclass-provided methods are being bound, and the `__getattr__` hook is never invoked to find the delegated methods instead:

```
>>> import aeidon
>>> class Wrapper(aeidon.Project): pass
... 
>>> wrapper = Wrapper()
>>> wrapper.open_main
<bound method Wrapper.open_main of <__main__.Wrapper object at 0x1106313a8>>
>>> wrapper.open_main.__self__
<__main__.Wrapper object at 0x1106313a8>
>>> wrapper._delegations['open_main']
<bound method OpenAgent.open_main of <aeidon.agents.open.OpenAgent object at 0x11057e780>>
>>> wrapper._delegations['open_main'].__self__
<aeidon.agents.open.OpenAgent object at 0x11057e780>
```

because the `open_main` method on `Project` still exists:

```
>>> Project.open_main
<function OpenAgent.open_main at 0x110602bf8>
```

As soon as you create an instance of `Project` those methods are deleted from the class:

```
>>> Project()
<aeidon.project.Project object at 0x1106317c8>
>>> Project.open_main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Project' has no attribute 'open_main'
```

and your wrapper would start to work as now the delegated `open_main` is found:

```
>>> wrapper.open_main
<bound method OpenAgent.open_main of <aeidon.agents.open.OpenAgent object at 0x11057e780>>
>>> wrapper.open_main.__self__
<aeidon.agents.open.OpenAgent object at 0x11057e780>
```

Your wrapper will have to do the deletions itself:

```
class Wrapper(aeidon.Project):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        for name in self._delegations:
            if hasattr(aeidon.Project, name):
                delattr(aeidon.Project, name)
```

Note that if the `aedion` maintainers replaced `self.__class__` with just `__class__` (no `self`) their code would still work *and* your subclass approach would also work without having to manually do the class clean-up again. That's because in Python 3, the `__class__` reference *in methods* is an automatic closure variable pointing to the class on which a method was  defined. For `Project._init_delegations()` that'd be `Project`. Perhaps you could file a bug report to that effect.