# Spooky action observed in Python context manager

Tags: python, contextmanager

Using contextmanager in Python 3 (I haven't tested Python 2) has some weird behavior regarding variables declared in the scope within the `with` clause.

It seems to me that the variables are behaving like 'spooky action at a distance' in the sense that only when observed they appear to exist (*joke from a non-physics savvy engineer*).

#### Inside a context managers scope, after the yield point:

If you...

1. print out `locals()`

then the variable does *not* exist.

But if you:

1. print out `locals()`;
2. do anything with the variable of the managed scope

**THEN THE VARIABLE EXISTS!!**

See this example:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

def groucho():
    @contextmanager
    def groucho_manager(**kwargs):
        yield
        print("groucho_manager locals", locals())
        a

    with groucho_manager(lolcat=10):
        a = 50

def harpo():
    @contextmanager
    def harpo_manager(**kwargs):
        yield
        print("harpo_manager locals", locals())

    with harpo_manager(lolcat=10):
        b = 100

groucho()
harpo()
```

outputs:

```py
groucho_manager locals {'kwargs': {'lolcat': 10}, 'a': 50}
harpo_manager locals {'kwargs': {'lolcat': 10}}
```

Possibly related to [Python class inheritance - spooky action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720339/python-class-inheritance-spooky-action), but I am not sure.

Comment: Variables from an enclosing function are only made available to inner functions if those inner functions *actually reference the variable at compile time*.  The implementation of such variables is rather more complex than ordinary local variables (since they can outlive the function that directly contains them); Python doesn't do this extra work unless explicitly necessary.  Context managers have nothing to do with this, it's a general property of nested function definitions.

Comment: Or in other words: `locals()` only returns the variables the function actually references, *not* every outer variable that it might potentially have referenced.

Comment: @jasonharper thx for answer. Is their anyway of testing for the existense of a variable **"potentially existing in locals"** ?
i mean: `getattr(locals(), 'var_name', default_value)`
does not work since the `var_name` has not been detected at compile time
so what to use then? only solution i see is a `try: ... except:...` clause but that seems nasty in this case

Comment: btw i have a *(potentially wicked, but in my mind legitimate)* reason for doing this: `with log_request(args):\n   response=send_request(args)` here it could be nice if `log_request` could prope for existence of `response` so it could log both the `request_args` and the `response` object

Comment: A context manager has NO general access to the local variables of the code being run under its control.  You're only able to see `a` in the first example because it's a function nested in the same scope, not because it's a context manager.

Answer (score 0):

My initial usecase was to make a `inner scope aware context manager` to take care of logging.

I thought i could abuse the odd behavior listed in the question, but as @jasonharper pointed out: its to do with nested scopes and not to be abused.

So... i decided to make a really hacky/abusive solution to all of this:

[scope_injected_contextmanager](https://pypi.org/project/scope-injected-contextmanager) **on pypi**

here is the simple example from the README:

```py
from scope_injected_contextmanager import scope_injected_contextmanager

fetch = lambda request: ("ok", 200)

@scope_injected_contextmanager
def log_request(request, response):
    print(f"request: {request} response: {response}")

with log_request:
    request = {
        "query_args": {
            'foo': 10
        }
    }
    response = fetch(request)

# prints
# request: {'query_args': {'foo': 10}} response: ('ok', 200)
```

see more at [github](https://github.com/sloev/scope_injected_contextmanager)

**beware... its:**

1. really hacky
2. completely not tested-enough
3. really ugly and abusive
4. uses inspect **heavily** (see 1-3)